# Nancy: Modify model in AfterRequest event?

Tags: c#, nancy

I want to add an `AfterRequest` event handler to my `Bootstrapper.cs` that is able to modify the model on the `Response` after every route is invoked. Is this possible? I don't see any properties on the Response where I could gain access to the Model (if there is one).

Here is my example usage (from `Bootstrapper.cs`):

```
 protected override void ApplicationStartup(..., IPipelines pipelines)
 {
    ...
    pipelines.AfterRequest += ModifyModel;
 }

 private void ModifyModel(NancyContext ctx)
 {
    // do things to the response model here
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still need this functionality you may be interested in an extension I just published on Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.ModelPostprocess.Fody. We needed a similar functionality in our project

This will allow you to modify your models after the route has already executed. Do have a look at the description on the [Bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/tpluscode/nancy.modelpostprocess)

Please tell me if this suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not that simple, you should inspect the ctx.Response.Content in order to know which deserializer is used and what object are you returning, I made a simple example returning a Foo Object Serialized as Json.....

```
    public class MyBootstrapper : Nancy.DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
        {
            base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

            pipelines.AfterRequest += ModifyModel;
        }

        private void ModifyModel(NancyContext ctx)
        {
            Foo foo;
            using(var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ctx.Response.Contents.Invoke(memory);

                var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());
                foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(str);
            }

            ctx.Response.Contents = stream =>
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    foo.Code = 999;
                    writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo));
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public class HomeModule : Nancy.NancyModule
    {
        public HomeModule()
        {

            Get["/"] = parameters => {
                return Response.AsJson<Foo>(new Foo { Bar = "Bar" });
            };
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something more straight-forward. I had a hunch that this was a pipe dream.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this more, this is simply not possible (at least within reason) to do with the Nancy framework as it exists today.